# How should I acknowledge Chinese Stack Exchange in my story?

Tags: translation

I'm making the final touches to my first story, and I intend to upload it to my webpage afterwards.  I want to add an acknowledgement that I received some assistance from Chinese Stack Exchange.

**Question**: How should I acknowledge Chinese Stack Exchange in my story?

In English I'd write:

> I acknowledge the use of the online forum Chinese Stack Exchange (`chinese.stackexchange.com`) for assistance writing a few sentences.

I translate this to:

> 我承认使用网络论坛《Chinese Stack Exchange》（`chinese.stackexchange.com`）帮助写一些句子。

I'm not keen on 承认 which seems more like "admit" (or "confess") than "acknowledge".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I write it in Traditional Chinese I will write that 我感謝網路論壇 Chinese Stack Exchange (chinese.stackexchange.com)，協助我完成一些句子。

Comment: Yes, I was about to comment why no "thank you" in the sentence. Just "acknowledging", or even to "confirm", 确认, sounds so official and bureaucratic. In Chinese, the thank you, 感謝, is wide enough to "acknowledge" assistance rendered, like acknowledging with thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am grateful to the netizens of CSE for their help and support, especially with my written Chinese.

我很感谢CSE网友的帮助和支持，尤其是在中文写作方面。